# Hibernate and SetDate does not set time

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm experiencing a strange behavior whit hibernate trying to update a Date field with a HQL query...

In a dao class I have this query

```
public void updateInterruttore(int idInterruttore, Date dateTime, boolean stato) {

        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        logger.debug("Datetime is " + dateTime);
        String update = "update Interruttore i set i.dateTime = :dateTime, i.stato = :stato where idInterruttore = :idInterruttore";
        session.createQuery(update).setDate("dateTime", dateTime).setBoolean("stato", stato)
                .setInteger("idInterruttore", idInterruttore).setLockOptions(LockOptions.UPGRADE).executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();

            }
```

For instance, the logger says me

```
Datetime is Sun Nov 20 23:31:23 CET 2016
```

But in the DB i have

```
20/11/2016 - 00:00:00
```

The model is

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_time")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm")
    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
```

and the DB field is TIMESTAMP, MySql DB

i'm creating DateTime in this way

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
Date now = date.toDate();
```

I have also tried this way with the same result

```
Date date = new Date();
Date now = new TimeStamp(date.getTime());
```

The orange thing i'm updating other Date objects in the application in a correct way...

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You need to use `setTimestamp()` not `setDate()`

Comment: Thanks! Did not see the wad setTimestamp!